# Mongos authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding, database, nosql

We have 9 mongo nodes in our environment with:

- 1 mongos
- 3 config servers (*mongod --configSvr*)
- 9 mongod servers (*shards or members of sharded replica-sets*)

and we are trying to implement authentication on them.

I have done this in the past with a single server and it was really easy:

1. just add the admin user to the admin database
2. add a user on each database

I had to restart mongod with `--auth` option, but here it doesn't seem to work.

I've added the admin account to our mongos and for our sharded databases; I tried to authenticate as the user I had just created, but it didn't work.

I've tried creating an admin user on each database, and the other user accounts that we need, but it still didn't work.

I also tried making sure all of our mongo servers were running with the `--keyFile` option specified either on the command-line or in their `/etc/mongodb.conf` files, but that didn't seem to help.

When I try to authenticate as a given user, like so:

```
db.auth("user","passwd")
```

it fails and returns `0`, as in `false`; not `non-zero`.

I seriously need all the help I can get, so please at least leave some suggestions on things I could try--I can't overstress this, any help is more than welcome since I don't seem to be getting anywhere just from following the official docs on managing/administrating mongo sharded clusters.

Comment: how'd you create said users?  Please post more code!  
**NOTE**  
mongos instances cannot start up with `--auth`, the config servers and shards are what provide the authentication/security. **ALSO** Make sure that you're running `db.auth("user", "password")` on the same database that you created the user you're trying to authenticate as.

Comment: At my workplace we tried creating users from the mongos and for some reason it didn't work reliably; when we created them directly on a config server it worked just fine. (we shutdown our mongos servers first, brought up new configs and then created the user directly on a config and then added some mongos servers)

Answer (score 1):

In a sharded cluster you should use `--keyFile` to allow all the members of the cluster to authenticate to each other.  When you use this option, `--auth` is "assumed".  Since there've been several version changes since you asked this question, the roles assigned to users are more granular now - you would need to have a 'clusterAdmin', 'userAdmin', 'dbAdmin', etc.

[This page has more details](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-security/) about how to configure security in MongoDB for a sharded cluster.